# language = {'name' : request.json['name']} TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, reactjs

I am trying to post data from react to flask api. I can post data from postman, but when I send data from my react application I get an error.

React app code:

```
export class App extends Component {

  async postData() {

    try{
      let state = {
        name: "cpp"
      }
      let result = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/lang', {
        method:'POST',
        mode:'no-cors',
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(state)
      });
      console.log(result)
      console.log(state)

    }catch(e){
      console.log(e)
      }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={ () => this.postData() }>Add adata</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Flask api code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request #import objects from the Flask model
app = Flask(__name__) #define app using Flask

languages = [{'name' : 'JavaScript'}, {'name' : 'Python'}, {'name' : 'Ruby'}]

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def test():
    return jsonify({'message' : 'It works!'})

@app.route('/lang', methods=['GET'])
def returnAll():
    return jsonify({'languages' : languages})

@app.route('/lang/<string:name>', methods=['GET'])
def returnOne(name):
    langs = [language for language in languages if language['name'] == name]
    return jsonify({'language' : langs[0]})

@app.route('/lang', methods=['POST'])
def addOne():
    language = {'name' : request.json['name']}
    languages.append(language)
    return jsonify({'languages' : languages})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8080) #run app on port 8080 in debug mode
```

when I press on the button I get the following error:

File "/Users/artur/Develop/API/untitled.py", line 21, in addOne
language = {'name' : request.json['name']}
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: I don't really know what is going on, but doesn't it just mean the request wasn't completed?

Comment: Could you try to change the name of your header `Content-type` to `Content-Type`. I'm not sure but it may be case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Use request.get_json() instead of request.json['name']

Comment: I have done this and it works, but it sends {"name":null} all the time now. Is there any way to fix this

Comment: never-mind, I solved this problem my adding ['name'] to request.get_json()